# Why does TTF_RenderText_Blended need a const char?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I am trying to use the result of a function to feed a string to TTF_RenderText_Blended.
this would mean it needs to be a variable,however. 
looking at the declaration it insists that the argument must be a const char.

Comment: Variable can be `const`.There is no contradiction here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean `const char *`, i.e. a pointer to a constant string (that's what the [reference manual](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/docs/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf_44.html) says), meaning the function can not modify the string. Which is precisely the meaning of using `const` here, to tell the compiler (and the user of the API) that the function will not modify the string. This allows you to pass a string literal safely to the function, for other strings just pass it normally and it will work just the same.